# Advanced sed command

Tags: sed

I have a file (`/usr/test.log`) with a bunch of lines, of the form

```
[enable/disable] [name] [stuff]
```

For example:

```
enable telnet max_pkt 0 max_payload 0 min_payload 1 disable_function 0 inherit_max_packets 0
enable telnets max_pkt 0 max_payload 0 min_payload 0 disable_function 0 inherit_max_packets 0
disable teredo max_pkt 0 max_payload 0 min_payload 40 disable_function 0 inherit_max_packets 0
```

Given a name and a status ("enable" or "disable"), what is a `sed` command to replace the line containing the given name with the given status? For example, given "telnet" and "disable", it would change the above first line to

```
disable telnet max_pkt 0 max_payload 0 min_payload 1 disable_function 0 inherit_max_packets 0
```

If there are simpler ways to programatically do those operations from the command line without using `sed`, that is fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it. Annoyingly, `|`, `(`, and `)` need escaping.

```
sed -i 's/^\(enable\|disable\) telnet/disable telnet/g' /usr/test.log
```

Comment: You need to enable [extended regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html) if you don't want to escape everything. In GNU sed, that's `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you want to replace it is just

```
sed -i 's/^enable telnet /disable telnet /g' filename
```

As long as now payload is in between [enable/disable] [name] this should be fine.
The "^" character is to match the begin of the line.

If you want to exchange the value regardless of the current state then you can use branching in sed

```
sed 's/^enable telnet /disable telnet /g 
     b end                                    #go to end if first rule has matched
     s/^disable telnet /enable telnet /g
     :end'  filename
```

Comment: Thanks. A priori I don't know the status of `telnet`. It could be either "enable" or "disable". What's the syntax for "or"?

Comment: I've tried `sed -i 's/^(enable|disable) telnet/disable telnet/g' filename` but that doesn't work.

Comment: oh now i got your question, or maybe i got it not.  The disable lines are allready disable why do you want to change them again? They are just feed through.

Answer (score 1):

With AWK:

```
tmp=$(mktemp); awk '$2=="telnet" {$1="disable"} {print}' test.log > $tmp && mv $tmp test.log
```

The above will write `disable` in the `telnet` line.

Scripting it:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=/path/to/test.log

usage() {
    cat <<-USAGE
    Enable/disable services in $file

    usage: ${0##*/} SERVICE [enable|disable]

    positional arguments:
      SERVICE   service name
    USAGE
    exitstatus=${1:-1}
    exit $exitstatus
}

error() {
    printf '%s: error: %s\n' "${0##*/}" "$1" 1>&2
    [ -z "$2" ] || exit $2
}

success() {
    printf '%s: Service `%s` %sd\n' "${0##*/}" "$service" "$status"
}

[ -f "$file" ] || error 'File not found.' 2

tmp=$(mktemp)

[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage

if [ $# -ne 2 ] || ( [ "$2" != "enable" ] && [ "$2" != "disable" ] ); then
    error 'Argument error.'
    usage 3
fi

service=$1
status=$2

awk -v status="$status" -v service="$service" -v ok=99 \
    '$2==service {$1=status; ok=0} {print} END{exit ok}' "$file" > $tmp
awkexit=$?
case $awkexit in
    0 )  mv $tmp "$file" && success;;
    99)  error 'Service not found.' 4;;
    * )  error 'Unkown error. Status change failed.' 5;;
esac
```

Change `file` to be the real path to the file in question. Save the script as e.g. `myservice`, make it executable, put it in your `PATH`, and then it can be executed like:

```
$ myservice telnet disable
myservice: Service `telnet` disabled.
```

The script will tell you if the status change was successful or if the service did not exist in the given file. I "abuse" the exit code of AWK to check status of the change.